# How to analyze a JSON parse multiple content from website?

Tags: html, json, csv, parsing

I'm pretty new here and have close to -1000000 of dev knowledge.

I'm trying to extract a content embedded in a line of a web site and converting this line in to a table (could be thru VBA).

The extraction point it's in a long HTML code like:

`<input type="hidden" name="name-here" value='[{"id":0,"name":"NAME","area":"Z","site":"https:\/\/www.a-site-here.com\/en\/index.html","logo":"https:\/\/www.another-site-here.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2022\/02\/image-GetFileAttachment1.png"},{...}]'/>`

Note that the JSON.parse line is multiple and have '},{' division.

So, I'm trying to build first in a HTML do this data extraction using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Just to check</h2> 

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
const txt = '{"id":0,"nome":"NAME","area":"Z","site":"https:\/\/www.a-site-here.com\/en\/index.html","logo":"https:\/\/www.another-site-here.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2022\/02\/image-GetFileAttachment1.png"},{...}'
const obj = JSON.parse(txt);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.id + ", " + obj.nome + ", " + obj.area + ", " + obj.site + ", " + obj.logo;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This code works using only one value '{content}', but the line have multi content as

'{contet1},{contet2} ... go on {last content}'

I was trying to replace the '},{' for a empty like '" "' using:

`const obj = JSON.parse(txt.replace(/},{/g, '" "'))`

But without success.

For the final result I expect one line per segment, each segment separated by comma for a kind of CSV file treatment.

I appreciate all help,

Comment: `{content1},{content2}` is not valid JSON in the first place. You would need to stick these objects into an array, `[{content1},{content2}]` - then you can loop over that.

Comment: _"You would need to stick these objects into an array"_ - which they already where, in the input field where you said you would get this from. So why are you testing with something different in the first place ...?

Comment: Hi @CBroe! Thank you for your comment! Actually I don't know the best way to extract the information inside the brackets. The ideia is just extract in rows each content and looking for the solution I stuck in this format. I'm noob in JSON, I'd checked the w3schools for some enlightenment but I'm still learning and understanding.

Comment: Parse the JSON, as-is, with those square brackets - then you will get an array as result. And an array is something you can easily loop over. (How to do that, rather belongs under "basics" though - so if you don't know, then it would be time for you to go find yourself some beginner tutorials on the matter now.)

Comment: Thank you @CBroe! I'll take a look how to do that! ASAP I'll return with the solution. I had no idea how basic is that. So, I need to: 1- Parse the JSON (getting the array) and 2- loop over. I appreciate your time and comment.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Hi @Rob! Thank you for your comment. Should I comment here my modification or answer my own question or edit it? Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

After a better search and comments from the community, I found the follow solution:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="list" value='[{"id":0,"name":"a","area":"x","site":"www1","logo":"www2"},{"id":1,"name":"b","area":"y","site":"www3","logo":"www4"}]'/>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Area</th>
      <th>Site</th>
      <th>Logo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
  var input = document.getElementById("list");
  var json = JSON.parse(input.value);

  var tableBody = document.getElementById("tableBody");
  json.forEach(function(obj) {
    var row = tableBody.insertRow();
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);    
    cell1.innerHTML = obj.id;
    cell2.innerHTML = obj.name;
    cell3.innerHTML = obj.area;
    cell4.innerHTML = obj.site;
    cell5.innerHTML = obj.logo;
  });
</script>
```

Thank you all for the comments!